# Chat Issue with Smartfox Server

Tags: javascript, smartfoxserver

Hi I'm running the http://www.impactjs.com  game engine with smartfox to create a multiplayer card game. I've run into an issue with the public chat api.

I'm getting an error on line 158 of the API when i try to send a publicmessage request

> TypeError: c[d].listener is undefined

Besides this everything else is almost fully implemented and all other API components are working great. Any smartfox experts out there?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, It turns out the listener function for another event was out of scope